# TYPO3 Fluid Array Access

Tags: php, arrays, typo3, fluid

I have a  question to access an array in fluid:

```
Associative Array {registrationProcess}
STRING  {fieldname} == 'firstName'
STRING  {property} == 'participant'
WORKING {registrationProcess.participant.{fieldname}}
WORKING {registrationProcess.{property}.firstName}
WORKING {registrationProcess.participant.firstName}
NULL    {registrationProcess.{property}.{fieldname}}
```

Why is the result of the  last notation NULL???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fluid currently only supports one dynamic property per level. Fluid 3.0 will change that but until that time, you have to extract the first dynamic expression to a variable and then perform the second dynamic expression on that new variable:

```xml
<f:variable
  name="registrationProperty"
  value="{registrationProcess.{property}}"
/>

{registrationProperty.{fieldname}}
```

Comment: ThX for the hint...
This is working

{f:variable(name: 'slug', value: '{property}.{fieldname}')}